# Unable to connect to the filesystem. Please confirm your credentials

Tags: wordpress, macos, ftp, localhost, elementor

I tried to install Elementor plugin for wordpress on Mac in localhost, but the installation has failed. These are the details:

Hostname: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins`

Ftp Username: `root`

Password:

With password I got this error alert:

```
Failed to connect to FTP Server /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins:21
```

With no password I got this error alert:

```
Unable to connect to the filesystem. Please confirm your credentials.
```

I search for similar cases and found that I have to add this line to the code:

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct’);
```

and then I got this message:

```
Installation failed. could not create directory.
```

I’m not familiar with code writing, and I’m new to Wordpress, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: I think your single quote is not same in syntax. 
Please use this -> define('FS_METHOD','direct');

Comment: Thanks.
Does it matter where this line is written in the code?

Comment: Yes, you need to add this line in wp-config.php at the end.

Answer (score 14):

try this command as it will not expose your entire html to hackers and this works in my case

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/your-project-name
```

Comment: chown: www-data: illegal group name

Answer (score 3):

It's probably due to lack of required filesystem permissions. Try this:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

Comment: This is a great way to get your system owned by hackers.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy way without any commands, Add this code in wp-config.php anywhere.

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

Answer (score 1):

## Macbook Solution:

#### Step 1:

edit `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` and replace

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

to

```
User YOUR_MACBOOK_USER_NAME   // apple
Group GROUP_NAME              // admin
```

after **Step 1**, you need to restart xampp, if you do not get your problem solve than follow **Step 2**

#### Step 2:

run this command

```
sudo chown -R YOUR_MACBOOK_USER_NAME:GROUP_NAME /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles

// like this

sudo chown -R apple:admin /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
```

**OR**

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP
```

## Ubuntu Solution:

run this command on terminal

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this error on Macbook, so I handle it the same as @Muhammad Numan instructed. Now, it worked

Step 1:
edit /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf and replace

User daemon
Group daemon
to

User YOUR_MACBOOK_USER_NAME   // apple
Group GROUP_NAME              // admin

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. Solution is go to applications/xampp/htdocs and right click on the wordpress folder on which you are trying to install plug-in or theme. click get info, scroll to bottom, click on the lock to unlock it and type in your password and enter, in sharing and permissions allow privilege to system,admin and everyone and click on the setting icon in bottom left and apply to enclosed items.

Answer (score 0):

give the permissions
use the following commands:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html;

sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} /;

sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} /;
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `find .`? Not `find /var/www/html`, or some other absolute path?

Answer (score -1):

This works for my mac  !!

1. In wp-config.php,add this `define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );`
2. In command line, execute `sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP`

Done